# Postgresql group by aliased jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to group by the result of a jsonb operation on an aliased field, but getting an error I would not expect.

The following work as expected:

```
select jsonb_build_object('x', 1) as a group by a;
select jsonb_build_object('x', 1) as a group by jsonb_build_object('x', 1)#>>'{x}';

    a     
----------
 {"x": 1}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
select jsonb_build_object('x', 1) as a group by a#>>'{x}';
ERROR:  column "a" does not exist
```

Is this a bug in postgresql (13.3)? Is there any way around it other than repeating the entire select expression in the group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alias (or a number referencing the position in the `SELECT` list) only when it stands alone and is not used inside an expression.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY) is not quite clear about that; all it says is

> In case of ambiguity, a `GROUP BY` name will be interpreted as an input-column name rather than an output column name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is thats you want to use a values of the json, but you can access his value at that position, what causes the error message

If you need need this, you need top

```
SELECT a FROM (select jsonb_build_object('x', 1) as a) t1  group by a#>>'{x}';
```

As the other option for using select columns in a Group by, doesn't allow you to select a value of the json, only the complete content of column

see also the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-agg.html)

[example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/exfkgCJpH9X4ped4S2PGpj/3)

Comment: I could certainly do that, but I'd rather avoid the subquery (it causes some other difficulties in my context). This doesn't explain why postgres lets you group by the alias but not by derivative expressions based on the alias.

Comment: yes it explains it very clearly, a cplumn for a group by can be taken from the select clause,that is why i placed it in a subquery so that it doesn't

Comment: "`a` has to exist prior to the `group by`" is incorrect: aliases *can* be used in `group by` -- but only by themselves and not as part of an expression.

Comment: so my is correct, you can't use a as json as he want a value of that json as group by amnd not a column values